# Spark Efficiently Extract Large Query Result From Relational DB

Tags: scala, apache-spark

(Spark beginner here) I wrote a Spark job to extract data from an Oracle database and write it to Parquet files. It works, but I am not satisfied with the batching solution I used. Is there a more efficient way?

I need to extract data from queries, not simply tables. I used a straightforward solution: get 1000 IDs (the max that can fit in a `WHERE` clause in Oracle), and built the query as a string. Then I passed it to Spark and extracted the data to Parquet. This works, but I wonder whether there are better, more efficient/idiomatic ways to do this. For instance, I am doing all the batching myself, whereas Spark was built to split and distribute work.

My code works on a small data set. I will have to scale it up by a factor of 100, and I would like to know the most idiomatic way of doing this.

```
  val query = 
        s"""
           |(SELECT tbl.*
           |FROM   $tableName tbl
           |WHERE  tbl.id IN (${idList.mkString("'", "','", "'")})
           |) $tableName
      """.stripMargin

  private def queryToDf(query: String, props: Properties)(implicit spark: SparkSession, appConfig: AppConfig): sql.DataFrame = {
    spark.read.format("jdbc")
      .option("url", appConfig.dbURL)
      .option("dbtable", query)
      .option("user", appConfig.dbUsername).option("password", appConfig.dbPassword)
      .option("fetchsize", appConfig.fetchsize.toString)
      .option("driver", appConfig.jdbcDriver)
      .load()
  }
```

Using Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.12, Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work better if you just let spark do all the work of distributing the data that is loaded and how to process it. Here you are making a `filter` before loading the data. I haven't worked with a `jdbc` source before, but I would assume that the query is passed to the `jdbc` before loading the data for spark.

So the solution is to pass the heavy work of filtering the data to spark, by making the property value of `dbtable` to the actual table name, and the query to spark:

```
val query = 
        s"""
           |(SELECT tbl.*
           |FROM   $tableName tbl
           |WHERE  tbl.id IN (${idList.mkString("'", "','", "'")})
           |) $tableName
      """.stripMargin

  private def queryToDf(tableName: String, query: String, props: Properties)(implicit spark: SparkSession, appConfig: AppConfig): sql.DataFrame = {
    spark.read.format("jdbc")
      .option("url", appConfig.dbURL)
      .option("dbtable", tableName)
      .option("user", appConfig.dbUsername).option("password", appConfig.dbPassword)
      .option("fetchsize", appConfig.fetchsize.toString)
      .option("driver", appConfig.jdbcDriver)
      .load()
      .selectExpr(query)
  }
```

I have not tested this tho, so there may be some mistakes (`query` could not be a valid for the `selectExpr()`, but shouldn't be that different).